# Error executing action install on resource 'windows_package[Node.js]'

Tags: node.js, powershell, chef-infra

I am trying to install workup in my parallels in Mac Book Pro.
I tried the command `workup` on **powershell** (in Administration Mode).
But when I run this command it throws this error as shown below and because of it I am not able to continue my further installation.
`Error executing action install on resource 'windows_package[Node.js]'`
 I am also adding the snapshot of the error . So, please refer to it as well.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved by ***uninstalling the node***.
There was mismatch in node versions. 
So, I uninstalled node from the system and workup itself install's node and it works after this.

Thanks :)